# assembler syntax depande on what (tools or micropro)?

Tags: assembly

hello dear programmers I have a question concerning the syntax of the assembler does it change according to the microprocessor I am using or the tool (nasm masm ......) or both thank you in advance. And I wish my question is very clear

Comment: Depends on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembler is generally created for a specific microprocessor with specified registers, instruction set, etc.  However, you develop for the syntax of the assembler - which can introduce structures (e.g. macros) on top of the hardware.

Comment: Not just macros / directives; some assemblers use different syntax even within instructions.  (Especially true for x86 where there are a few major families of syntax (Intel, AT&T, and Go), and some minor ones (HLA).  And within Intel syntax, there are many flavours, like NASM `mov edi, symbol` vs. MASM/TASM/GAS-intel's `mov edi, OFFSET symbol`  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info